# How to check from php code running in terminal (PHPUnit) if php code running in Apache will be able to write to a folder?

Tags: php, apache, permissions, phpunit

I have file_put_contents code in PHPUnit that can always successfully write a file to a folder with permissions 744.

I have identical file_put_contents website code that cannot write to the same folder unless I max out permissions to 777.

The PHPUnit code is giving me a sort of false positive.

Comment: Are you sure that you should be testing this in your unit tests? It sounds like you're trying to test something in the environment external to your code. What's your goal here? (Note also that permission bits are only part of the story. File and directory ownership, ACLs, etc. can also have an impact.)

Comment: If your running PHPUnit on a CLI, then this will be running as the user your logged in as, Apache is most likely using a different user (www-data probably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the unit test and the website under two different user accounts. The one you use for your unit tests has permission to write to your folder, the other one doesn't.

There are two possibilities I see here:

- Run the unit test with the webserver-user
- Change the folder permissions

## Running as a different user

Using sudo (or su), you can change the user which will run the command. In doing so, both operations have the same permissions. If one fails, the other will too.

```
sudo -u username command
```

## Change the folder permissions

Unix has a user and a group assigned to each file and folder. First, create a group for both your users:

```
groupadd WebsiteGroup
```

The add your users to that group

```
usermod -aG WebsiteGroup user1
usermod -aG WebsiteGroup user2
```

Now assign the group to your folder using `chown`/`chgrp`. Now when you run your tasks, the group permission is the one that determines success or failure for both.

Man Pages for

- [groupadd](https://linux.die.net/man/8/groupadd)
- [usermod](https://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod)
- [chown](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown)

Comment: This is only par of the story. There are many more potential restrictions like file general system access and php modules. In short: you can check a number of things, but you will never get a reliable answer this way.

Comment: sudo -u is good enough for now. Later on I'll add a curl request that hits a page on the actual site that then attempts to write a file and then I'll test for that. That approach should work fine on both the local dev server and live server.